# mysql Select row with most recent date per user - make it faster

Tags: mysql, sql, database

records in my table are like below:

```
id    |sensor_id|val  |audit_date
255245|        1|22.12|2017-02-18 08:26:47
```

and I want get latest records using this

```
SELECT `sensor_id`, `val`, `audit_date` 
FROM `tests` t1
JOIN (SELECT max(`audit_date`) as audit_date, `sensor_id` 
   from `tests` group by `sensor_id`) t2
USING (`audit_date`, `sensor_id`)
   where `id` > (select max(`id`)-1000 from `tests`)
```

It takes more than one second; without last "where" - second and half.
"id" is primary key and now indexes.
What I can do to make this query faster?

Comment: Please post the **SHOW CREATE TABLE tests;** and also the **EXPLAIN** of you query

Comment: CREATE TABLE tests (
  id int(2) NOT NULL,
  sensor_id int(2) NOT NULL,
  val float NOT NULL,
  audit_date datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: 1 PRIMARY t1 range PRIMARY PRIMARY 4  593 Using where 
1 PRIMARY <derived2> ref key0 key0 13 <cut>.t1.audit_date,<cut>.t1.sensor_id 10  
3 SUBQUERY        Select tables optimized away 
2 DERIVED tests ALL     1771020 Using temporary; Using filesort

Answer (score 0):

This query return latest instered record using max() funtion

```
SELECT t1.sensor_id,val,t1.audit_date 
FROM `tests` t1
JOIN (SELECT max(`audit_date`) as audit_date, max(`sensor_id`) as max_sensor_id 
FROM `tests` group by `sensor_id`) t2
ON t2.max_sensor_id = t1.sensor_id
AND t2.audit_date =t1.audit_date
```

Comment: results is OK, but it takes close to two seconds.

Comment: you can also do this without join but some time group by not working properly see here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160216/group-by-gives-wrong-result-with-min-aggregate-function

Answer (score 0):

You can try if a self-exclusion join would be faster:

```
SELECT t1.sensor_id, t1.val, t1.audit_date
FROM audit t1
  LEFT JOIN audit t2
  ON t1.sensor_id = t2.sensor_id
  AND t2.audit_date > t1.audit_date 
where 
  t2.id is null
```

Basically that says return records for which there are no greater `audit_date`s per `sensor_id`.